# nothing showing up in LineChart

Tags: javafx, charts

When I run the code I get a chart with no data points or lines. Within the for loop I add each line of a data table, and each such line should be a line in the chart. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```
public class PartiesApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    public void start(Stage stage){
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1967, 2009, 4);
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        // set the titles for the axes
        xAxis.setLabel("Year");
        yAxis.setLabel("Ranking");

        // create the line chart. The values of the chart are given as numbers
        // and it uses the axes we created earlier
        LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
        lineChart.setTitle("Relative support of the parties");
        lineChart.setLegendVisible(true);
                Scene view = new Scene(lineChart, 640, 480);

        
        Scanner reader = new Scanner("partiesdata.tsv");
        
        String firstLine = reader.nextLine();
        String[] years = firstLine.split("\t");
        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            String line = reader.nextLine();
            String[] partyData = line.split("\t");
            
            XYChart.Series data = new XYChart.Series();
            data.setName(partyData[0]);
            
            for (int i = 1; i < partyData.length; i++) {
                data.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(years[i], Double.valueOf(partyData[i])));
            }
            lineChart.getData().add(data);
            
            stage.setScene(view);
            stage.show();
        }
        
        
    }

}
```

Comment: the api doc is your friend ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```java
Scanner reader = new Scanner("partiesdata.tsv");
```

Is using [this constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) of `Scanner` whose Javadoc says:

> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces values **scanned from the specified string** *[emphasis added]*.

In other words, the scanner is using the `"partiesdata.tsv"` string itself as the source of data. That is probably not what you actually want to do. I'm assuming you meant to open up a resource or file whose name is `partiesdata.tsv`.

If a resource then you'll want to use one of the constructors that accepts a `java.io.InputStream`. For example:

```java
String res = "/partiesdata.tsv"; // may not be the correct path for you
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream(res))) {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    // parse data...
  }
}
```

If a file then you'll want to use one of the constructors that accepts a `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.Path`. For example:

```java
Path file = Path.of("partiesdata.tsv"); // may not be the correct path for you
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    // parse data...
  }
}
```

---

Additionally, these two statements:

```java
stage.setScene(view);
stage.show();
```

Should be moved outside the `while` loop.

Comment: Doesn't one of the constructors of the Scanner class take a file path as an argument? "parties.tsv" is the name of the file that is in the source folder. Why wouldn't it read that file line by line?

Comment: Not as a `String`. You can [see for yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#constructor.summary) what constructors are available.